# I have "deleted" /var/log folder. What can I do to repare this mistake?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd, php, mysql

My `/` partition vas full, so I needed to make some free space... The quickest solution I've found was to "move" `/var/log` to another partition and make a symbolic link to it.
In fact I did a `cp` of the directory, and then a `rm` of the original... Unfortunately, I did a `cp` witout `-p` option, so I did not keep mode and ownership... So my logs files are not longer modified.

This server is a LAMP server. Apache is still working but do not log anything. This is the same for mysql... I am afraid to restart computer because actually website is still working.
Giving write access to all files do not change anything (`chmod -R a+rw`)

What can I do to clean the server ? Can I restart with an empty `/var/log/` folder ?

---

edit: I had to restart apache so that it recreates the log files. This part is OK now, but some other service do not log anymore.
Perhaps should I restart the server... But the problem is for subdirectories which won't be created automatically.

Is there an apt command to reinstall package and recreate theses logs subdirectories (with good users) ?

Comment: When you delete open files (e.g. apache logs) then the files aren't truly deleted; the application still writes to the old file and still use space in `/var/log`.  You just can't see the file anymore, because you deleted the name.  You can possibly see these deleted files with `sudo lsof | grep -i apache.*del`.  Restarting the apache daemon will cause it to close the old files (and so recover the space) and try to open new files.

Comment: What commands did you use to move it? You said "move" then you said "cp", which I'd call a copy not a move.

Comment: This here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171713/relinking-an-anonymous-unlinked-but-open-file?rq=1 explains how to create a file name for a file that doesn't have one any more but is still open.